# How to show one by one nodes in Vis JS directed graph

Tags: javascript, graph, directed-graph, vis.js

Need to show one by one sorted order nodes with directed graph in vis js like a video on a play button event.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a loop where you add a new node say once every second to your DataSet with nodes. The Network will automatically update.